# Why does my Google Reader show Recommended Subscriptions?

Tags: google-reader

Recently, my Google Reader changed to show all the Recommended items in the list. I don't want to see them as I like controlling what is in the list (from my specific groups). How do I change it back?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to remove the Recommended items. [See this short discussion on Google.](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/reader/thread?tid=32a62161a8503082&hl=en)

There is a greasemonkey script that you can use to [remove the Explore section entirely.](http://blog.arpitnext.com/2009/10/remove-new-explore-feature-google-reader-using-greasemonkey.html)